# Why does SN 12.66 say aging-and-death has acquisition as its source?

Tags: pali-canon

[SN 12.66](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.66/en/bodhi) says:

> *The many diverse kinds of suffering that arise in the world headed by aging-and-death: this suffering has acquisition as its source,
>   acquisition as its origin; it is born and produced from acquisition.
>   When there is acquisition, aging-and-death comes to be; when there is
>   no acquisition, aging-and-death does not come to be.*

Why does SN 12.66 say aging-and-death has acquisition (upadhi) as its source? Why doesn't SN 22.66 say aging-and-death has cancer or heart disease as its source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, of course, refers to Dependent Origination, with *upadhi* used synonymously with *upādāna*.

Pali Text Society's dictionary equates it with *taṇhā*:

> **Upadhi**, (fr. upa + dhā, cp. upadahati & BSk. upadhi Divy 50, 224, 534) 1. putting down or under, foundation, basis, ground, substratum (of rebirth) S. I, 117, 124, 134, 186; A. II, 24 (°saṅkhaya); III, 382 (id.); IV, 150 (°kkhaya); It. 21, 69; Sn. 364, 728 (upadhī-nidānā dukkha = vaṭṭa-dukkhaṃ SnA 505), 789, 992; Nd1 27, 141; Nd2 157; Vbh. 338; Nett 29; DhA. IV, 33.—**(2) clinging to rebirth (as impeding spiritual progress), attachment (almost syn. with kilesa or taṇhā, cp. nirupadhi & anupadhi)**; S A. = pañcakkhandhā, S. II, 108. At M I 162 (cp. Sn. 33 = S. I, 6 = I. 107) **wife and children, flocks and herds, silver and gold are called upadhayo**. upadhi is the root of sorrow ib. 454; S. II, 108; Sn. 728 = 1051 = Th. I, 152 and the rejection of all upadhis is Nibbāna D. II, 36. (cp. S. I, 136; III, 133; V, 226; A. I, 80; M. I, 107 = II. 93; Vin. I, 5, 36 = J. I, 83 = Mvst II. 444; It. 46, 62); D. III, 112 calls that which has upadhi ignoble (= non-Aryan). At S. I, 117 = Divy 224 upadhi is called a bond (saṃgo). Cp. opadhika.—The upadhis were later systematized into a set of 10, which are given at Nd2 157 as follows: 5 taṇh’upadhis (taṇhā, diṭṭhi, kilesa, kamma, duccarita), āhār-upadhi, paṭigh°, catasso upādinnā dhātuyo u. (viz. kāma, diṭṭhi, sīlabbata, attavāda; see D. III, 230), cha ajjhattikāni āyatanāni u. , cha viññāṇa-kāyā u. Another modified classification see at Brethren p. 398. (Page 142)

In my understanding, the idea here is that the pursuit of acquisitions has a [semiotic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/semiotic) effect of cementing the notion of self as an agent of action and enjoyer of its results. And so craving for an object, setting one's mind onto the object, making the object one's target, pursuing the object, acquiring the object, and then enjoying the contact with the object is exactly the semiotic sequence that leads to *bhava* - becoming (=identifying self as) a sentient being.

While experience of "contact" with an "object" marks the point when the *spatial* sense of self has fully matured, it is pursuit and acquisition is what helps the *temporal* sense of self to come to fruition.

Once self-identification as sentient being has fully matured both spatially and temporally, the self imputed  onto the aggregates becomes subject to change of the aggregates, hence "aging-and-death".

Comment: Pali context doesn't allow upadhi to refer to upādāna, that's why the tipitaka memorizer wrote in aṭṭhakathā as " [Khandhapañcakaṃ hettha upadhīti adhippetaṃ.](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=12&A=3020&h=Khandhapa%C3%B1caka%E1%B9%83,hettha%20upadh%C4%ABti%20adhippeta%E1%B9%83)". If the context allows both of them, the tipitaka memorizer must mention both, upādāna and khandha. That's why my answer seriously focusing on the context and compare them to the others sutta, especially [saccapabba](http://84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=10&item=294&items=7).

Answer (score 1):

Upādhi means clinging aggregates.

The context of [sammasasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=16&item=254&items=9&h=ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81,samuda,nirodh,g%C4%81min%C4%AB%20pa%E1%B9%ADipad%C4%81,loke%20piyar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83,s%C4%81tar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83) is the four noble truth, ariya**sacca**. See the [highlight](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=16&item=254&items=9&h=ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81,samuda,nirodh,g%C4%81min%C4%AB%20pa%E1%B9%ADipad%C4%81,loke%20piyar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83,s%C4%81tar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83), and compare with **sacca**pabba of DN [mahāsatipaṭṭhānasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=10&item=294&items=7&h=up%C4%81d%C4%81nakkhandh%C4%81,samuday,ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81,loke%20piyar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83%20s%C4%81tar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83,nirodh,g%C4%81min%C4%AB,pa%E1%B9%ADipad%C4%81,jar%C4%81,mara%E1%B9%87a).

See [atthakathā of this sutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=12&A=3020) for more information.

Another, [paṭiccasamuppāda](http://84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=16&item=1&items=3&h=up%C4%81d%C4%81nakkhandh%C4%81,samuday,ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81,loke%20piyar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83%20s%C4%81tar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83,nirodh,g%C4%81min%C4%AB,pa%E1%B9%ADipad%C4%81,jar%C4%81,mara%E1%B9%87a,up%C4%81d%C4%81na) is an alternative of Ariyasacca. They are difference in literal, but same in meaning.

**[sammasasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=16&item=254&items=9&h=ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81,samuda,nirodh,g%C4%81min%C4%AB%20pa%E1%B9%ADipad%C4%81,loke%20piyar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83,s%C4%81tar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83)**

```
     [256]   Bhagavā   etadavoca   idha   bhikkhave  bhikkhu  sammasamāno
sammasati    antaraṃ   sammasaṃ   yaṃ   kho   idaṃ   anekavidhaṃ   nānappakārakaṃ
dukkhaṃ   loke   uppajjati   jarāmaraṇaṃ  idaṃ  nu  1-  kho  dukkhaṃ  kiṃnidānaṃ
kiṃsamudayaṃ   kiṃjātikaṃ   kiṃpabhavaṃ   kismiṃ   sati   jarāmaraṇaṃ   hotīti   .  so
sammasamāno   evaṃ   jānāti   yaṃ   kho   idaṃ  anekavidhaṃ  nānappakārakaṃ

Dukkhaṃ    loke   uppajjati   jarāmaraṇaṃ   idaṃ   kho   dukkhaṃ   upadhinidānaṃ
upadhisamudayaṃ   upadhijātikaṃ   upadhippabhavaṃ   upadhismiṃ   sati   jarāmaraṇaṃ   hoti
upadhismiṃ   asati   jarāmaraṇaṃ   na  hotīti  .  so  jarāmaraṇañca  pajānāti
jarāmaraṇasamudayañca     pajānāti    jarāmaraṇanirodhañca    pajānāti    yā
ca    jarāmaraṇanirodhasāruppagāminī    paṭipadā    tañca   pajānāti   tathā
paṭipanno   ca   hoti   anudhammacārī   .   ayaṃ   vuccati  bhikkhave  bhikkhu
sabbaso sammā dukkhakkhayāya paṭipanno jarāmaraṇanirodhāya.
     [257]   Athāparaṃ   sammasamāno   sammasati   antaraṃ  sammasaṃ  upadhi
panāyaṃ   kiṃnidāno   kiṃsamudayo   kiṃjātiko   kiṃpabhavo   kiṃsmiṃ   sati  upadhi
hoti   kismiṃ   asati   upadhi   na   hotīti   .  so  sammasamāno  evaṃ
jānāti     upadhi     taṇhānidāno     taṇhāsamudayo     taṇhājātiko
taṇhāpabhavo   taṇhāya   sati   upadhi   hoti   taṇhāya   asati  upadhi  na
hotīti    .    so    upadhiñca    pajānāti   upadhisamudayañca   pajānāti
upadhinirodhañca    pajānāti   yā   ca   upadhinirodhasāruppagāminī   paṭipadā
tañca  pajānāti  tathā  paṭipanno  ca  hoti  anudhammacārī  .  ayaṃ  vuccati
bhikkhave bhikkhu sabbaso sammā dukkhakkhayāya paṭipanno upadhinirodhāya.
     [258]   Athāparaṃ   sammasamāno   sammasati  antaraṃ  sammasaṃ  taṇhā
panāyaṃ  kattha  uppajjamānā  uppajjati  kattha  nivīsamānā  nivīsatīti  1-.
So   sammasamāno   evaṃ   jānāti   yaṃ   kho  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ
etthesā    taṇhā    uppajjamānā    uppajjati   ettha   nivīsamānā
@Footnote: 1 Ma. Yu. nivisamānā nivisatīti. evamuparipi.
Nivīsati   .   kiñci   loke   piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  .  cakkhuṃ  loke  piyarūpaṃ
sātarūpaṃ   .pe.   sotaṃ   loke   piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  ...  ghānaṃ  loke
piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  ...  jivhā  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ ... Kāyo loke
piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  ...  mano  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā
uppajjamānā uppajjati ettha nivīsamānā nivīsati.
```

**[mahāsatipaṭṭhānasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=10&item=294&items=7&h=up%C4%81d%C4%81nakkhandh%C4%81,samuday,ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81,loke%20piyar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83%20s%C4%81tar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83,nirodh,g%C4%81min%C4%AB,pa%E1%B9%ADipad%C4%81,jar%C4%81,mara%E1%B9%87a)**

```
     [294]   Puna  caparaṃ  bhikkhave  bhikkhu  dhammesu  dhammānupassī  viharati
catūsu     ariyasaccesu     .    kathañca    bhikkhave    bhikkhu    dhammesu
dhammānupassī   viharati   catūsu   ariyasaccesu  .  idha  bhikkhave  bhikkhu  idaṃ
dukkhanti   yathābhūtaṃ   pajānāti   ayaṃ   dukkhasamudayoti   yathābhūtaṃ  pajānāti
ayaṃ    dukkhanirodhoti    yathābhūtaṃ    pajānāti    ayaṃ    dukkhanirodhagāminī
paṭipadāti yathābhūtaṃ pajānāti [1]-.
     {294.1}  Katamañca  bhikkhave  dukkhaṃ ariyasaccaṃ. Jātipi dukkhā jarāpi
dukkhā       maraṇampi      dukkhaṃ      sokaparidevadukkhadomanassupāyāsāpi
@Footnote: 1 Ma. paṭhamabhāṇavāro niṭṭhito.
Dukkhā   appiyehi   sampayogopi   dukkho   piyehi   vippayogopi  dukkho
yampicchaṃ    na    labhati   tampi   dukkhaṃ   saṅkhittena   pañcupādānakkhandhā
dukkhā.
     [295]  Katamā  ca  bhikkhave  jāti  .  yā  tesaṃ  tesaṃ  sattānaṃ
tamhi    tamhi   sattanikāye   jāti   sañjāti   okkanti  nibbatti  1-
abhinibbatti   khandhānaṃ   pātubhāvo   āyatanānaṃ   paṭilābho   ayaṃ  vuccati
bhikkhave jāti.
     {295.1}  Katamā  ca  bhikkhave  jarā  .  yā  tesaṃ tesaṃ sattānaṃ
tamhi  tamhi  sattanikāye  jarā  jīraṇatā  khaṇḍiccaṃ  pāliccaṃ  valitacatā 2-
āyuno saṃhāni indriyānaṃ paripāko ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave jarā.
     {295.2}  Katamañca  bhikkhave  maraṇaṃ  .  yā 3- tesaṃ tesaṃ sattānaṃ
tamhā  tamhā  sattanikāyā  cuti  cavanatā  bhedo  antaradhānaṃ  maccu maraṇaṃ
kālakiriyā  khandhānaṃ  bhedo  kaḷevarassa  nikkhepo jīvitindriyassa upacchedo
idaṃ vuccati bhikkhave maraṇaṃ.
     {295.3} Katamo ca bhikkhave soko. Yo kho bhikkhave aññataraññatarena
byasanena    samannāgatassa    aññataraññatarena    dukkhadhammena    phuṭṭhassa
soko  socanā  socitattaṃ  antosoko  antoparisoko ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave
soko.
     {295.4} Katamo ca bhikkhave paridevo. Yo kho bhikkhave aññataraññatarena
byasanena    samannāgatassa    aññataraññatarena    dukkhadhammena    phuṭṭhassa
ādevo  paridevo  ādevanā  paridevanā  ādevitattaṃ  paridevitattaṃ ayaṃ
vuccati bhikkhave paridevo.
@Footnote: 1 Ma. ayaṃ pāṭho natthi. 2 valittacatātipi pāṭho. 3 Ma. yaṃ.
Katamañca   bhikkhave   dukkhaṃ   .   yaṃ  kho  bhikkhave  kāyikaṃ  dukkhaṃ  kāyikaṃ
asātaṃ   kāyasamphassajaṃ   dukkhaṃ   asātaṃ   vedayitaṃ   idaṃ  vuccati  bhikkhave
dukkhaṃ.
     {295.5}  Katamañca  bhikkhave  domanassaṃ  .  yaṃ kho bhikkhave cetasikaṃ
dukkhaṃ   cetasikaṃ   asātaṃ  manosamphassajaṃ  1-  dukkhaṃ  asātaṃ  vedayitaṃ  idaṃ
vuccati bhikkhave domanassaṃ.
     {295.6}  Katamo  ca  bhikkhave  upāyāso  .  yo  kho  bhikkhave
aññataraññatarena      byasanena      samannāgatassa      aññataraññatarena
dukkhadhammena      phuṭṭhassa     āyāso     upāyāso     āyāsitattaṃ
upāyāsitattaṃ ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave upāyāso.
     {295.7}  Katamo  2-  ca  bhikkhave  appiyehi sampayogo dukkho.
Idha  yassa  te  honti  aniṭṭhā  akantā  amanāpā  rūpā  saddā gandhā
rasā  phoṭṭhabbā  [3]-  ye  vā  panassa  honti anatthakāmā ahitakāmā
aphāsukakāmā   ayogakkhemakāmā  tesaṃ  4-  saṅgati  samāgamo  samodhānaṃ
missībhāvo ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave appiyehi sampayogo dukkho.
     {295.8} Katamo ca bhikkhave piyehi vippayogo dukkho. Idha yassa te
honti   iṭṭhā  kantā  manāpā  rūpā  saddā  gandhā  rasā  phoṭṭhabbā
ye  vā  panassa  honti  atthakāmā hitakāmā phāsukakāmā yogakkhemakāmā
mātā   vā   pitā  vā  bhātā  vā  bhaginī  vā  mittā  vā  amaccā
vā    ñātisālohitā   vā   tesaṃ   asaṅgati   asamāgamo   asamodhānaṃ
amissībhāvo ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave piyehi vippayogo dukkho 2-.
@Footnote: 1 cetosamphassajanti vā pāṭho. 2-2 Yu. ime pāṭhā natthi. 3 Ma. dhammā.
@ito paraṃ īdisameva. 4 Ma. yā tehi saddhiṃ saṅgati ... ito paraṃ īdisameva.
     {295.9}   Katamañca  bhikkhave  yampicchaṃ  na  labhati  tampi  dukkhaṃ .
Jātidhammānaṃ   bhikkhave  sattānaṃ  evaṃ  icchā  uppajjati  aho  vata  mayaṃ
na   jātidhammā   assāma   na   ca  vata  no  jāti  āgaccheyyāti  na
kho   panetaṃ   icchāya   pattabbaṃ   idampi   yampicchaṃ   na   labhati  tampi
dukkhaṃ   .   jarādhammānaṃ   bhikkhave   sattānaṃ  .  byādhidhammānaṃ  bhikkhave
sattānaṃ   .   maraṇadhammānaṃ   bhikkhave   sattānaṃ   .   sokaparidevadukkha-
domanassupāyāsadhammānaṃ   bhikkhave   sattānaṃ   evaṃ   icchā   uppajjati
aho    vata   mayaṃ   na   sokaparidevadukkhadomanassupāyāsadhammā   assāma
na    ca   vata   no   sokaparidevadukkhadomanassupāyāsā   āgaccheyyunti
na    kho   panetaṃ   icchāya   pattabbaṃ   idampi   yampicchaṃ   na   labhati
tampi   dukkhaṃ   .   katame   ca  bhikkhave  saṅkhittena  pañcupādānakkhandhā
dukkhā    .   seyyathīdaṃ   rūpūpādānakkhandho   1-   vedanūpādānakkhandho
saññūpādānakkhandho      saṅkhārūpādānakkhandho      viññāṇūpādānakkhandho
ime   vuccanti   bhikkhave   saṅkhittena   pañcupādānakkhandhā   dukkhā .
Idaṃ vuccati bhikkhave dukkhaṃ ariyasaccaṃ.
     [296]  Katamañca  bhikkhave  dukkhasamudayo 2- ariyasaccaṃ. Yāyaṃ taṇhā
ponobbhavikā    3-    nandirāgasahagatā    tatratatrābhinandinī   seyyathīdaṃ
kāmataṇhā bhavataṇhā vibhavataṇhā.
     [297]   Sā  kho  panesā  bhikkhave  taṇhā  kattha  uppajjamānā
uppajjati   kattha   nivisamānā   nivisati   .  yaṃ  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ
@Footnote: 1 Ma. rūpupādānakkhandho ... viññāṇupā .... 2 Ma. dukkhasamudayaṃ.
@3 Sī. Yu. ponobhavikā.
Etthesā    taṇhā    uppajjamānā    uppajjati   ettha   nivisamānā
nivisati.
     {297.1}  Kiñca  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  .  cakkhuṃ  loke piyarūpaṃ
sātarūpaṃ    etthesā    taṇhā    uppajjamānā    uppajjati    ettha
nivisamānā   nivisati   .   sotaṃ   loke   .  ghānaṃ  loke  .  jivhā
loke  .  kāyo  loke  .  mano  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā
taṇhā uppajjamānā uppajjati ettha nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.2} Rūpā loke. Saddā loke. Gandhā loke. Rasā loke.
Phoṭṭhabbā   loke   .   dhammā   loke   piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā
taṇhā uppajjamānā uppajjati ettha nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.3}   Cakkhuviññāṇaṃ   loke   .   sotaviññāṇaṃ   loke .
Ghānaviññāṇaṃ  loke  .  jivhāviññāṇaṃ  loke  .  kāyaviññāṇaṃ  loke.
Manoviññāṇaṃ   loke   piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā  uppajjamānā
uppajjati ettha nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.4} Cakkhusamphasso loke. Sotasamphasso loke. Ghānasamphasso
loke  .  jivhāsamphasso  loke . Kāyasamphasso loke. Manosamphasso
loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā  uppajjamānā uppajjati ettha
nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.5}  Cakkhusamphassajā  vedanā loke. Sotasamphassajā vedanā
loke  .  ghānasamphassajā  vedanā  loke  .  jivhāsamphassajā  vedanā
loke   .  kāyasamphassajā  vedanā  loke  .  manosamphassajā  vedanā
loke   piyarūpaṃ   sātarūpaṃ   etthesā   taṇhā  uppajjamānā  uppajjati
Ettha nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.6}  Rūpasaññā  loke  .  saddasaññā  loke . Gandhasaññā
loke   .  rasasaññā  loke  .  phoṭṭhabbasaññā  loke  .  dhammasaññā
loke   piyarūpaṃ   sātarūpaṃ   etthesā   taṇhā  uppajjamānā  uppajjati
ettha nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.7}   Rūpasañcetanā   loke  .  saddasañcetanā  loke .
Gandhasañcetanā   loke  .  rasasañcetanā  loke  .  phoṭṭhabbasañcetanā
loke   .   dhammasañcetanā  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā
uppajjamānā uppajjati ettha nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.8}  Rūpataṇhā  loke  .  saddataṇhā  loke . Gandhataṇhā
loke  .  rasataṇhā  loke . Phoṭṭhabbataṇhā loke. Dhammataṇhā loke
piyarūpaṃ   sātarūpaṃ   etthesā   taṇhā   uppajjamānā  uppajjati  ettha
nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.9}  Rūpavitakko  loke . Saddavitakko loke. Gandhavitakko
loke    .   rasavitakko   loke   .   phoṭṭhabbavitakko   loke  .
Dhammavitakko   loke   piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā  uppajjamānā
uppajjati ettha nivisamānā nivisati.
     {297.10}  Rūpavicāro  loke. Saddavicāro loke. Gandhavicāro
loke . Rasavicāro loke. Phoṭṭhabbavicāro loke. Dhammavicāro loke
piyarūpaṃ   sātarūpaṃ   etthesā   taṇhā   uppajjamānā  uppajjati  ettha
nivisamānā nivisati. Idaṃ vuccati bhikkhave dukkhasamudayo ariyasaccaṃ.
     [298]   Katamañca   bhikkhave  dukkhanirodho  1-  ariyasaccaṃ  .  yo
@Footnote: 1 Ma. dukkhanirodhaṃ.
Tassāyeva   taṇhāya   asesavirāganirodho   cāgo   paṭinissaggo   mutti
anālayo.
     {298.1}   Sā  kho  panesā  bhikkhave  taṇhā  kattha  pahīyamānā
pahīyati    kattha    nirujjhamānā    nirujjhati    .   yaṃ   loke   piyarūpaṃ
sātarūpaṃ   etthesā   taṇhā   pahīyamānā   pahīyati  ettha  nirujjhamānā
nirujjhati.
     {298.2}   Kiñca   loke   piyarūpaṃ   sātarūpaṃ   .  cakkhuṃ  loke
piyarūpaṃ    sātarūpaṃ    etthesā   taṇhā   pahīyamānā   pahīyati   ettha
nirujjhamānā   nirujjhati   .   sotaṃ  loke  .  ghānaṃ  loke  .  jivhā
loke  .  kāyo  loke  .  mano  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā
taṇhā pahīyamānā pahīyati ettha nirujjhamānā nirujjhati.
     {298.3}  Rūpā  loke  .  saddā loke. Gandhā loke. Rasā
loke  .  phoṭṭhabbā  loke  .  dhammā loke piyarūpaṃ sātarūpaṃ etthesā
taṇhā pahīyamānā pahīyati ettha nirujjhamānā nirujjhati.
     {298.4}   Cakkhuviññāṇaṃ   loke   .   sotaviññāṇaṃ   loke .
Ghānaviññāṇaṃ  loke  .  jivhāviññāṇaṃ  loke  .  kāyaviññāṇaṃ  loke.
Manoviññāṇaṃ   loke   piyarūpaṃ   sātarūpaṃ   etthesā  taṇhā  pahīyamānā
pahīyati ettha nirujjhamānā nirujjhati.
     {298.5} Cakkhusamphasso loke. Sotasamphasso loke. Ghānasamphasso
loke. Jivhāsamphasso loke. Kāyasamphasso loke. Manosamphasso loke
piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā  pahīyamānā  pahīyati ettha nirujjhamānā
nirujjhati.
     {298.6}  Cakkhusamphassajā  vedanā loke. Sotasamphassajā vedanā
Loke  .  ghānasamphassajā  vedanā  loke  .  jivhāsamphassajā  vedanā
loke   .  kāyasamphassajā  vedanā  loke  .  manosamphassajā  vedanā
loke    piyarūpaṃ    sātarūpaṃ   etthesā   taṇhā   pahīyamānā   pahīyati
ettha nirujjhamānā nirujjhati.
     {298.7}  Rūpasaññā  loke  .  saddasaññā  loke . Gandhasaññā
loke  .  rasasaññā  loke . Phoṭṭhabbasaññā loke. Dhammasaññā loke
piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā  pahīyamānā  pahīyati ettha nirujjhamānā
nirujjhati.
     {298.8}   Rūpasaññacetanā  loke  .  saddasañcetanā  loke .
Gandhasañcetanā   loke  .  rasasañcetanā  loke  .  phoṭṭhabbasañcetanā
loke   .  dhammasaññacetanā  loke  piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā
pahīyamānā pahīyati ettha nirujjhamānā nirujjhati.
     {298.9}  Rūpataṇhā  loke  .  saddataṇhā  loke . Gandhataṇhā
loke  .  rasataṇhā  loke . Phoṭṭhabbataṇhā loke. Dhammataṇhā loke
piyarūpaṃ  sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā  pahīyamānā  pahīyati ettha nirujjhamānā
nirujjhati.
     {298.10}  Rūpavitakko  loke. Saddavitakko loke. Gandhavitakko
loke  .  rasavitakko  loke  .  phoṭṭhabbavitakko  loke. Dhammavitakko
loke   piyarūpaṃ   sātarūpaṃ  etthesā  taṇhā  pahīyamānā  pahīyati  ettha
nirujjhamānā nirujjhati.
     {298.11} Rūpavicāro loke. Saddavicāro loke. Gandhavicāro loke.
Rasavicāro  loke  .  phoṭṭhabbavicāro loke. Dhammavicāro loke piyarūpaṃ
Sātarūpaṃ   etthesā   taṇhā   pahīyamānā   pahīyati  ettha  nirujjhamānā
nirujjhati. Idaṃ vuccati bhikkhave dukkhanirodho ariyasaccaṃ.
     [299]  Katamañca  bhikkhave  dukkhanirodhagāminī  paṭipadā  ariyasaccaṃ .
Ayameva  ariyo  aṭṭhaṅgiko  maggo  seyyathīdaṃ  sammādiṭṭhi  sammāsaṅkappo
sammāvācā   sammākammanto   sammāājīvo   sammāvāyāmo   sammāsati
sammāsamādhi.
     {299.1}  Katamā  ca  bhikkhave  sammādiṭṭhi. Yaṃ kho bhikkhave dukkhe
ñāṇaṃ    dukkhasamudaye    ñāṇaṃ   dukkhanirodhe   ñāṇaṃ   dukkhanirodhagāminiyā
paṭipadāya ñāṇaṃ ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave sammādiṭṭhi.
     {299.2}  Katamo  ca  bhikkhave  sammāsaṅkappo. Nekkhammasaṅkappo
abyāpādasaṅkappo avihiṃsāsaṅkappo ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave sammāsaṅkappo.
     {299.3}  Katamā  ca  bhikkhave  sammāvācā . Musāvādā veramaṇī
pisuṇāya   vācāya   veramaṇī   pharusāya   vācāya  veramaṇī  samphappalāpā
veramaṇī ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave sammāvācā.
     {299.4}   Katamo  ca  bhikkhave  sammākammanto  .  pāṇātipātā
veramaṇī   adinnādānā   veramaṇī   kāmesu   micchācārā  veramaṇī  ayaṃ
vuccati bhikkhave sammākammanto.
     {299.5} Katamo ca bhikkhave sammāājīvo. Idha bhikkhave ariyasāvako
micchāājīvaṃ  pahāya  sammāājīvena  jīvikaṃ  kappeti  ayaṃ  vuccati  bhikkhave
sammāājīvo.
     {299.6}  Katamo  ca  bhikkhave  sammāvāyāmo. Idha bhikkhave bhikkhu
anuppannānaṃ  pāpakānaṃ  akusalānaṃ  dhammānaṃ anuppādāya chandaṃ janeti vāyamati
Viriyaṃ    ārabhati    cittaṃ   paggaṇhāti   padahati   uppannānaṃ   pāpakānaṃ
akusalānaṃ   dhammānaṃ   pahānāya   chandaṃ   janeti  vāyamati  viriyaṃ  ārabhati
cittaṃ     paggaṇhāti     padahati     anuppannānaṃ    kusalānaṃ    dhammānaṃ
uppādāya   chandaṃ   janeti   vāyamati   viriyaṃ  ārabhati  cittaṃ  paggaṇhāti
padahati     uppannānaṃ     kusalānaṃ    dhammānaṃ    ṭhitiyā    asammosāya
bhiyyobhāvāya   vepullāya   bhāvanāya  pāripūriyā  chandaṃ  janeti  vāyamati
viriyaṃ   ārabhati   cittaṃ   paggaṇhāti   padahati   .  ayaṃ  vuccati  bhikkhave
sammāvāyāmo.
     {299.7}  Katamā  ca  bhikkhave  sammāsati  .  idha  bhikkhave  bhikkhu
kāye   kāyānupassī   viharati   ātāpī   sampajāno   satimā   vineyya
loke    abhijjhādomanassaṃ    vedanāsu   vedanānupassī   viharati   .pe.
Citte   .pe.   dhammesu   dhammānupassī   viharati   ātāpī   sampajāno
satimā   vineyya   loke   abhijjhādomanassaṃ   .   ayaṃ  vuccati  bhikkhave
sammāsati.
     {299.8} Katamo ca bhikkhave sammāsamādhi . Idha bhikkhave bhikkhu vivicceva
kāmehi  vivicca  akusalehi  dhammehi  savitakkaṃ  savicāraṃ vivekajaṃ pītisukhaṃ paṭhamaṃ
jhānaṃ   upasampajja   viharati  vitakkavicārānaṃ  vūpasamā  ajjhattaṃ  sampasādanaṃ
cetaso   ekodibhāvaṃ   avitakkaṃ   avicāraṃ  samādhijaṃ  pītisukhaṃ  dutiyaṃ  jhānaṃ
.pe.  tatiyaṃ  jhānaṃ  upasampajja  viharati  sukhassa  ca  pahānā  dukkhassa  ca
pahānā    pubbe    va   somanassadomanassānaṃ   atthaṅgamā   adukkhamasukhaṃ
upekkhāsatipārisuddhiṃ   catutthaṃ   jhānaṃ  upasampajja  viharati  .  ayaṃ  vuccati
Bhikkhave  sammāsamādhi  .  idaṃ  vuccati  bhikkhave  dukkhanirodhagāminī  paṭipadā
ariyasaccaṃ.
     {299.9}   Iti   ajjhattaṃ   vā   dhammesu   dhammānupassī  viharati
bahiddhā    vā   dhammesu   dhammānupassī   viharati   ajjhattabahiddhā   vā
dhammesu   dhammānupassī   viharati   samudayadhammānupassī  vā  dhammesu  viharati
vayadhammānupassī    vā    dhammesu    viharati   samudayavayadhammānupassī   vā
dhammesu   viharati   .   atthi   dhammāti   vā  panassa  sati  paccupaṭṭhitā
hoti   yāvadeva   ñāṇamattāya  paṭissatimattāya  .  anissito  ca  viharati
na  ca  kiñci  loke  upādiyati  .  evampi  kho  bhikkhave  bhikkhu dhammesu
dhammānupassī viharati catūsu ariyasaccesu.
                     Saccapabbaṃ niṭṭhitaṃ.
```

**[paṭiccasamuppāda](http://84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=16&item=1&items=3&h=up%C4%81d%C4%81nakkhandh%C4%81,samuday,ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81,loke%20piyar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83%20s%C4%81tar%C5%ABpa%E1%B9%83,nirodh,g%C4%81min%C4%AB,pa%E1%B9%ADipad%C4%81,jar%C4%81,mara%E1%B9%87a,up%C4%81d%C4%81na)**

```
     [2]   Bhagavā   etadavoca   katamo  ca  bhikkhave  paṭiccasamuppādo
avijjāpaccayā     bhikkhave     saṅkhārā     saṅkhārapaccayā    viññāṇaṃ
viññāṇapaccayā    nāmarūpaṃ   nāmarūpapaccayā   saḷāyatanaṃ   saḷāyatanapaccayā
phasso      phassapaccayā      vedanā      vedanāpaccayā      taṇhā
taṇhāpaccayā     upādānaṃ     upādānapaccayā     bhavo    bhavapaccayā
Jāti     jātipaccayā     jarāmaraṇaṃ     sokaparidevadukkhadomanassupāyāsā
sambhavanti   .   evametassa  kevalassa  dukkhakkhandhassa  samudayo  hoti .
Ayaṃ vuccati bhikkhave paṭiccasamuppādo.
     [3]    Avijjāya    tveva   asesavirāganirodhā   saṅkhāranirodho
saṅkhāranirodhā     viññāṇanirodho     viññāṇanirodhā     nāmarūpanirodho
nāmarūpanirodhā      saḷāyatananirodho     saḷāyatananirodhā    phassanirodho
phassanirodhā   vedanānirodho  vedanānirodhā  taṇhānirodho  taṇhānirodhā
upādānanirodho   upādānanirodhā   bhavanirodho   bhavanirodhā  jātinirodho
jātinirodhā   jarāmaraṇaṃ   sokaparidevadukkhadomanassupāyāsā   nirujjhanti .
Evametassa   kevalassa   dukkhakkhandhassa   nirodho   hotīti  .  idamavoca
bhagavā    attamanā    te   bhikkhū   bhagavato   bhāsitaṃ   abhinandunti  .
```

Comment: I marked this answer down because it is just links . If it was improved by providing a complete readable answer, I would mark it up.

Comment: I wasted half an hour for format it. Although, I wasted my time to ask for highlight function to the webmaster and looking for the highlight script to him, **but now I still have to waste the time to format it**. Why the asker just asked?

Answer (score 1):

Becoming alive is equivalent to acquiring a self-view - objectification, inner/outer first (unlike viruses), all other dimensions second. This aquisition brings about the fear of the end of that self-view. Without self-view, birth is not possible.